# How to retrieve address of storage bytes arrays longer than 31bytes?

Tags: solidity, addresses, storage

If I deploy the following contract in Remix the bytes array test get stored at address 0x00 in storage.

```
contract parseBytes {
  bytes test = "\x20\x00\x10";
  function f() {
    assembly{
        test //should push address of test bytes array and offset to stack
        pop //should pop offset
    }
  }
}
```

If I extend the bytes array to longer than 31 bytes the storage looks:

0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000: 41
0x290decd9548b62a8d60345a988386fc84ba6bc95484008f6362f93160ef3e563: a020001000100001000e238989d74a050072b08989d74a050040000f0204000000

So it seems that the 32bytes get stored elsewhere (at address 0x290...). How can I retrieve this address using inline assembly? Executing the function above the stack contains the values:

0: 0x2d        //is not the address of the bytes array in storage

1: 0x26121ff0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.8;

contract parseBytes {
  bytes test = "\x20\x00\x10\x10\x10";
  function f(){
    bytes32 adr;
    assembly{
        adr := sha3(0, 32)
    }
  }
}
```

Bytes and string are stored in storage at sha3(slot). So in this case slot is `0`. In below code `adr` gives the address from which `test` is stored.